# Performance of putc and putchar?

Tags: c, printf, putchar

I have always thought that calling putc multiple times is faster than puts or printf. To print "hello" for example, in a real program I would always use puts or printf, but now I'm writing a program that generates C code, so I was wondering whether to generate code as `putchar('h'); putchar('e') ...` because I first thought it should be more faster. But I ran a test which gave a very interesting result. The compiler is GCC.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t timer;
    FILE *f;
    int i;

    f = fopen("out.txt", "w");

    #define START_TIMER(TIMER) TIMER = clock()
    #define ELAPSED_TIME(TIMER)\
    (double)(clock() - TIMER) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC

    enum { NUM_ITERS = 9999999 };
    START_TIMER(timer);
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ITERS; i++) {
        putc('h', f);
        putc('e', f);
        putc('l', f);
        putc('l', f);
        putc('o', f);
        putc('\n', f);
    }
    printf("%.3f\n", ELAPSED_TIME(timer));
    START_TIMER(timer);
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ITERS; i++) {
        fputs("hello", f);
    }
    printf("%.3f\n", ELAPSED_TIME(timer));
    START_TIMER(timer);
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ITERS; i++) {
        fprintf(f, "hello\n");
    }
    printf("%.3f\n", ELAPSED_TIME(timer));
    return 0;
}
```

result without optimization:

**4.247**
1.013
1.195

result with optimization (-O2):

0.910
1.184
1.315

result with optimization (-O3):

0.920
1.158
1.311

So calling putc multiple times is slower than puts of printf when executing naively without optimization. First, I'm curious why so. Second, which way should I follow for the program-generated C code?

Comment: Have you tried a longer string than just "hello"?

Comment: a) Is this the most important problem you could be working on for this program right now? b) Anyone who has to maintain a `putc()` version will hunt you down and poke you in the eye with a pointy stick.

Comment: @Mike The machine-generated code is not intended for human reading.

Comment: @xiver77: When things don't work right, someone will read the code.

Comment: @R.. I've just tried with "hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello" with -O0, the result is `35.488 5.232 5.844` and with -O3 it is `6.906 5.051 5.867` so calling putc multiple times seems to be even more slower with longer text, even with optimization.

Comment: If the machine generated code is not intended for human reading then why does it matter how it looks? Just generate whatever works and is correct.

Comment: Btw fprintf has to do formatting of the string you give it so it makes sense that it takes some extra overhead.

Comment: @Brandin What I truly need now is a `puts` without an additional '\n' at the end.

Comment: @xiver77 what's wrong with `fputs("foo",fp)`

Comment: @Brandin thanks I've just re-checked the reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuition for what should be faster is wrong. Generally, `putc`/`putchar` is going to have a lot of overhead per byte written, since there's a whole cycle of function call, potential locking of the stdio stream (`stdout`) being targetted, etc. per byte. On the other hand, functions like `printf` or `puts` have more overhead *per call* than `putc` (e.g. `printf` has to process the format string, and `puts` has to call `strlen` or equivalent), but that overhead only happens once, no matter how many bytes you're writing. The actual write can take place as a bulk copy to the `FILE`'s buffer, or a bulk write to the underlying file (if the `FILE` is unbuffered).

As for how optimization levels affect this, `-O0` probably has a lot more overhead around making the function call which gets optimized out at higher optimization levels.